# How to set up divs without spacing in between?

Tags: css, html, css-position

I want to set up a div structure like this (where there is a div on top, and two divs under) but I don't want to use any tables. Also there can't be any spacing between the divs, and if possible I want the borders to be collapsed.

```
 _________
|         |
|_________|
|    |    |
|____|____|
```

This doesn't seem to work.

```
<div></div>
<br/>
<div></div><div></div>
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried anything with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vjhKb/)

HTML

```html
<div class="topdiv"></div>
<div class="leftbottom"></div>
<div class="rightbottom"></div>
```

CSS

```css
.topdiv{
    background-color:red;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;    
}
.leftbottom{
     background-color:yellow;
    width:100px;
    height:100px; 
    position:relative;
    float:left;

}
.rightbottom{
     background-color:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;

}
```

**EDIT:** With regards to your *borders-collapse* issue, I will not apply in this case as we are using div's which by default have no border unless you manually assign the same.

Comment: If the divs have a border, is there a way to collapse them?

Comment: Like i said, By default they do not have any. Unless you assign them manually like this. border:2px solid #a1a1a1;

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u5EYY/).

`div` is a block level element. That means nothing can sit either side of it by default. You can use floating to change this behaviour. Or you can change the `display` attribute. `display: inline-block` works well but is not supported in older browsers. Here's an example using `float`.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">top</div>
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 150px;
}
.top {
 border: solid 1px blue;
}
.left {
 border: solid 1px red;   
    width: 73px;
    float:left;
}
.right {
 border: solid 1px green; 
    width: 73px;
    float:right;
}
```

[Documentation for `display`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)
[Documentation for `float`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
div
{
    margin: 0;
}

#container
{
    font-size: 0;
}

.top
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 202px;
}

.bottom
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NgakP/1/

Comment: The fiddle does not do what was requested

Comment: Why not. This is exactly accoring to the OP's requirements

Answer (score 1):

You have to use CSS.

You give a style class to your div and then the float:right, float:left properties should allow you to reach your goal in disposing the bottom divs. you can then use in block style to put them one right upon the other.

Answer (score 1):

Display the bottom two inline-block. There will be a break after the first div by default.

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/2MBWT/2/

Dont forget the borders take up space as well

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.column {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 149px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width:100px;height:50px;"></div>
<br />
<div style="width:100px">
    <div style="width:50px;height:50px;float:left;display:inline-block;"></div>
    <div style="width:50px;height:50px;float:right;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because divs have "block" as default display-type, which means that every div begins a new line. There are several ways to solve this problem  using css.
I would use "float".

HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
   <div class="fullWidth"></div>
   <div class="halfWidthContainer">
       <div class="halfWidth green"></div>
       <div class="halfWidth blue"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#container{
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
   border: 2px solid red;
}
.fullWidth{
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   background: #aaa;
}
.halfWidth{
   width: 150px;
   height: 100px;
   float: left;
}
.green{
   background: green;
}
.blue{
   background:blue;
}
```

Of course, the classes ".green" and ".red" are optional and just for demonstration purposes. Also, you might not give your divs a fixed height, so that the height fits the Content.

If you use padding or margin, keep in mind that they will influence your total width of the elements. For example, when giving your .halfWith a padding of 10, that means that its with will have a total of 190 (with of 150 plus left margin of 20 plus right margin of 20). You would have to set the with of .halfWith to 110 so that the total with would be half of your container with again.

Comment: FYI you're missing a closing `div`.